# How to get the value of a handler/runnable timer?

Tags: android

I'm currently using a runnable and handler to have a timer which updates a textview every second.

```
public class TimerFragment extends Fragment {


    TextView tvTimer;
    long startTime = 0;
    Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            int seconds = (int)(millis/1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;
            tvTimer.setText(String.format("%d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
            timerHandler.postDelayed(this,500);
        }
    };



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_timer, null);

        tvTimer = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);
        Button btn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn1);

        btn.setText("Start");
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button b = (Button) v;

                if (b.getText().equals("Stop")){
                    timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
                    b.setText("Start Monitoring");
                }

                else {
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
                    b.setText("Stop");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Monitoring started.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

How do i get the value of the timer? Like for example, showing a toast when the text becomes "0:15". I want to be able to get the value so I can use it. The function I have in mind is having the user set a time and have a toast or notification pop up when the timer passes through that time (like 15 or 30 seconds). But right now what I want to know is how to get the value of the timer. Thanks!

Comment: Inside the Runnable you have the minutes and seconds available. Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a CountDownTimer to set a countdown based on interval set by you and it will stop when the time has come in future

```
 CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)

  // Example : I've set countdown for 30 seconds 

CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    text_view.setText(millisUntilFinished / 1000 + " " + "Sec");
                }

                public void onFinish() {
// implement your code customization here after interval is over
                    text_view.setText("time over!");
                }
            }.start();
```

[For more insights refer the Android Developer reference for CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer)